# Is there a way to assign weights to features when using the caret R package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, r-caret

I want to train a binomial glm model using the `caret` package in R. I have run PCA on my data first, so each feature of the data is a PC. Now, I want to weight each feature by the amount of variance a given PC explains. How can I do it?

The `train` function provides the `weights` parameter, however, it is for case (outcome) weights, not for feature weights.

Comment: Hi it should be helpful if you try to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When performing PCA with `caret` in data preprocessing it is not necessary to calculate the weights, the package itself does this in an automated way, [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213983/accessing-pca-components-from-caret-object-in-r).

Comment: @bbiasi So if I preprocess my data with PCA using caret, will it then automatically use those weights while training the model? And will those weights for sure be equal to the amount of variance explained by each component? The link you provided does not really answer my questions.